# Need help interacting with multiples MySql table using tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, mysql-python

I'm a beginner so sorry if this question sounds stupid for some of you :)

So basically I have to create a graphical interface with tkinter where I can interact with 3 tables. I've found good tutorials explaining how to list the content of a table, edit it, delete data etc so this part shouldn't be hard.

My problem is that I don't know how to interact with multiple tables in the same tkinter graphical interface.

[Basically I want this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTyry.jpg) in every tabs like shown in the second 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BiP5.jpg)

I don't think it's that hard but i really have no experience with tkinter, I'm probably missing something very easy.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: See [ttk.notebook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#notebook).

Comment: @acw1668 i know about ttk.notebook the thing i don't understand is how to write code that apply specifically to one tab, the code for the database management is 100+ lines, i don't understand how to "apply" this code only to a specific tab

Comment: Put the form in the first image in a `Frame` and then add the frame to a tab of the notebook.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks a lot :D